# Is google apps scripting available on New Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites-2016

This last Forum discussion from May 2017 said this was on the roadmap: anyone knows of an update?

Answer (score -2):

A rebuilt version of Sites was launched on November 22, 2016. Apps Script cannot currently access or modify Sites made with this version, but script can still access classic Sites.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/